# What implementations were used in Technical Report on C++ Performance, TR 18015?

Tags: c++, performance

In [Technical Report on C++ Performance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/18015.html) there are a lot of tables that compare different implementations of C++. Unfortunately nothing is said about an OS and compiler used. I wonder if this information is available unofficially or at least can be inferred out of the technical report itself.

Comment: I glanced into the report, and I am not sure that the practical implementation matters much. For instance, virtual functions obviously should take about the same time as indirect calls to pointers, etc... So I guess that the conclusions are not very sensitive to the implementation. But I may be wrong.

Comment: The point is not all implementations were equally good. And it's interesting for me which one was the best.

Comment: But things have changed since then. Many compilers (e.g. GCC) got newer versions, with significant improvement, notably for C++.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought things can get extrapolated from 2006 to now. I'd be glad if you point me to some up to date comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From page 23 in the report: "Most comments about run-time costs are based on a set of simple measurements performed on **three different machine architectures using six different compilers** run with a variety of optimization options. Each test was run multiple times to ensure that the results were repeatable. The code is presented in Appendix D:. The aim of these measurements is neither to get a precise statement of optimal performance of C++ on a given machine nor to provide a comparison between compilers or machine architectures. Rather, the aim is to give developers a view of relative costs of common language constructs using current compilers, and also to show what is possible (what is achieved in one compiler is in principle possible for all)."

So I guess if you really want to know, you could ask the report's authors.